# beginCluster function takes a very long time

Tags: r, parallel-processing, raster

I'm trying to go parallel with a moving window operation on a large RasterStack with a function that calls `overlay()`. The issue is, that setting up a cluster with `raster::beginCluster` takes a very long time (more than 18 hours so far) and hasn't succeeded yet. Any suggestions? I work with a 125 GB RAM remote instance with 32 cores. I have tried to set up the cluster with 31, 28 or only 4 cores and neither way it worked. Nor did `beginCluster(31, type = "SOCK")`. Setting up clusters with other packages, eg. `doParallel` or `snow` do work, though.

cheers,
Ben

Comment: Which OS? Have you large objects in your current environment? (use `format(sum(sapply(ls(), object.size)), big.mark = ",")`).

Comment: OS is Windows Server >= 2012 x64 and object size is 912